# Separating hexadecimal escape sequences in strings

Tags: c

Can a string constant like `"foo" "\x01" "bar"` be written as a single string literal (while keeping the hexadecimal notation)? With `"foo\x01bar"` the escape sequence seems to be interpreted as `\x01ba` since I get the warning "hex escape sequence out of range."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"foo" "\x01" "bar"` *is* a string literal.

The C standard states that a hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can constitute the escape sequence. Without the explicit concatenation (which is the common workaround to this problem), the compiler parses `\x01ba` which is obviously out of range.

Comment: Maybe "atomic" string literal is a better description.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Unfortunately a hexadecimal-escape-sequence is *defined* as any number of valid hexadecimal digits following after `\x`. As opposed to that, an *octal*-escape-sequence (`\001`) runs no longer than three octal digits (*6.4.4.4 Character constants*). So, no, either you need to "play tricks" with hex notation, or you go for octal (which isn't *that* bad once you get used to it).

Answer (score 1):

How about `"foo\x01\142ar"`? Is that cheating?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to simply write the escaped character in octal, instead of hexadecimal

```
"foo\1bar"
```

and no more ambiguity...

Comment: (and if "bar" is a number, use up to 3 octal digits, like `\001`)