# hex escape sequence out of range for numeric escape of C

Tags: c, syntax

When I `printf` following code, I get `hex escape sequence out of range`. `\x1b` is `numeric escape` for `ESC`. If my string is literally the `1ESC1`, how to represent it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("1\x1b1\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: See this question (use adjacent string literals): [Separating hexadecimal escape sequences in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571520/separating-hexadecimal-escape-sequences-in-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\x1b is numeric escape for ESC" is true, but the *hex escape sequence* here is `\x1b1`, not `\x1b`.

Avoid `printf(st)` to print a *string* `st`.  The first argument to `printf()` is for a format.  OK in OP's case, but better to avoid that maybe some escape sequence was used that was the same as `%`.

Try `puts("1" "\x1b" "1");`.

Answer (score 0):

suggest correcting the syntax:

```
printf("1\x1b\1\n");
```

Comment: Thank you, It works!!  Could you explain a little about the syntax of second `\`? Just  tell me the terminology or reference.